# PHP auto generate pdf file for salaryslip

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am using tcpdf to generate the pdf file for employee salary , how can I sent automatically email employee salary (pdf)to end of the month

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php

Comment: Setup the cron job to run "your php file" at end of every month. "Your php file" will include code to send email to all employees with their respective salary-slips.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a cronjob to send the email every month end.

```
59 23 28-31 * * [ &quot;$(date +%d -d tomorrow)&quot; = &quot;01&quot; ] &amp;&amp; /path/to/you/script.php
```

Source:
https://blog.nexcess.net/2013/05/09/cron-job-for-the-last-day-of-the-month/